# How to reference array items of json object in T-SQL

Tags: arrays, sql-server, json, t-sql

I am using the JSON functionality in SQL Server 2016.  How do I reference an item in the $.people[] array as shown below, using a variable?  Instead of hardcoding the "1" in the path parameter of the JSON_QUERY function, I want to use a variable and loop through each item in the people array.

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{
    "people": [{
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe"
    }, {
        "name": "Jane",
        "surname": null,
        "active": true
    }]
}';

select JSON_QUERY(@json,'$.people[1]'); -- this works
declare @test nvarchar(max) = '$.people[1]';
select JSON_QUERY(@json,@test); -- ERROR: The argument 2 of the "JSON_VALUE or     JSON_QUERY" must be a string literal.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL through the `sp_executesql` procedure.

Both the original `select` statement, and the `sp_executesql` have the same output listed at the bottom.

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = '{
    "people": [{
        "name": "John",
        "surname": "Doe"
    }, {
        "name": "Jane",
        "surname": null,
        "active": true
    }]
}';

declare @i int = 1
declare @dyn_sql nvarchar(1000) = 
    'select json_query(@json_dyn, ''$.people[' + cast(@i as varchar(10)) + ']'');'

select JSON_QUERY(@json,'$.people[1]'); -- this works

exec sp_executesql @dyn_sql --set the SQL to run
    , N'@json_dyn nvarchar(max)' --"declare" the variable in the SQL to run
    , @json_dyn = @json --"set" the variable in the SQL to run

/*
Output : {          "name": "Jane",          "surname": null,          "active": true      }
*/
```